# Imagemagick convert from PHP, to draw 2 borders on image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I would like to take a simple image file (500px width example) from a folder, in PHP and do exec('/usr/bin/convert -etc.') to the image and achieve this: http://imm.io/media/3O/3O7j.jpg . Basically, I want to draw 2 colored borders/rectangles around the image at that specific positions. Can anybody help compose such a command, or is it possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be easier using the GD extension in PHP. Specifically, the [`imagesetstyle()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetstyle.php) function to set line dashes, and [`imageline()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageline.php) to draw the lines.

This example loads an image and draws a dashed line on it. You should be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
<?php
$im  = imagecreatefromjpeg('/your/file.jpg');
$w   = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

/* Draw a dashed line, 5 red pixels, 5 white pixels */
$style = array($red, $red, $red, $red, $red, $w, $w, $w, $w, $w);
imagesetstyle($im, $style);
imageline($im, 0, 0, 100, 100, IMG_COLOR_STYLED);

imagejpeg($im, '/path/to/save.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: What happens if I got a PNG file ? imagecreatefrompng ? Does it work right ? What about GIFs ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in that case use `imagecreatefrompng()` and `imagecreatefromgif()` respectively. Note tha when you use the latter, you may want to create a new true color image and copy the loaded gif image onto it, so that you have a true color image to work with. Alternatively, you could also `file_get_contents()` the image and use `imagecreatefromstring()` which can autodetect the filetype.